# Serving SVG content from static/assets folder in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I have a lot of SVGs in my site and they have lots of paths so I don't want to clutter my code with them, but display the full code in the browser.

In PHP there's a magic function called `file_get_contents('path')`

Is there an alternative to this in Nuxt? So far the only option is to serve it as a regular `img` tag which prohibits all styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `@nuxtjs/svg` module ([NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/svg)). Using that module you can import your svgs in your script and use them like components in your template.

```js
<template>
  <NuxtLogo class="logo" />
</template>
 
<script>
  import NuxtLogo from "~/assets/nuxt.svg?inline";
 
  export default {
    components: { NuxtLogo },
  };
</script>

<style scoped>
.logo {
  fill: #fff;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You're amazing.